# In C++ what are the benefits of using exceptions and try / catch instead of just returning an error code?

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch

I've programmed C and C++ for a long time and so far I've never used exceptions and try / catch. What are the benefits of using that instead of just having functions return error codes?

Comment: See James Curran answer for the __>  2  <__ main reasons.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Possibly an obvious point - a developer can ignore (or not be aware of) your return status and go on blissfully unaware that something failed.

An exception needs to be acknowledged in some way - it can't be silently ignored without actively putting something in place to do so.

Comment: You got one of the two points: You can easily move the code for handling errors to a non local point (higher up the call change) that knows how to handle a problem given a more extensive context.

Answer (score 29):

The advantage of exceptions are two fold:

- **They can't be ignored.**  You must deal with them at some level, or they will terminate your program.  With error code, you must explicitly check for them, or they are lost.
- **They can be ignored.**  If an error can't be dealt with at one level, it will automatically bubble up to the next level, where it can be.  Error codes must be explicitly passed up until they reach the level where it can be dealt with.

Comment: this should be the best answer IMO !

Comment: could you please elaborate the 2nd point (maybe with code sample) i don't understand it very well - Thank You.

Comment: @Xsmael Assume FuncA() calls FuncB() which calls FuncC() which calls FuncD().  FuncD() can throw an exception, and if there are no catches in FuncB or FuncC, it can be caught in FuncA().  Using an error code, FuncC must accept the code from FuncD and specifically return it to FuncB.

Comment: oh, is see now, so  from FuncA() i can catch any exception that has been throw in any of the nested functions B,C,D.... no matter how deep it goes ?

Answer (score 18):

The advantage is that you don't have to check the error code after each potentially failing call.  In order for this to work though, you need to combine it with RAII classes so that everything gets automatically cleaned up as the stack unwinds.

With error messages:

```
int DoSomeThings()
{
    int error = 0;
    HandleA hA;
    error = CreateAObject(&ha);
    if (error)
       goto cleanUpFailedA;

    HandleB hB;
    error = CreateBObjectWithA(hA, &hB);
    if (error)
       goto cleanUpFailedB;

    HandleC hC;
    error = CreateCObjectWithA(hB, &hC);
    if (error)
       goto cleanUpFailedC;

    ...

    cleanUpFailedC:
       DeleteCObject(hC);
    cleanUpFailedB:
       DeleteBObject(hB);
    cleanUpFailedA:
       DeleteAObject(hA);

    return error;
}
```

With Exceptions and RAII

```
void DoSomeThings()
{
    RAIIHandleA hA = CreateAObject();
    RAIIHandleB hB = CreateBObjectWithA(hA);
    RAIIHandleC hC = CreateCObjectWithB(hB);
    ...
}

struct RAIIHandleA
{
    HandleA Handle;
    RAIIHandleA(HandleA handle) : Handle(handle) {}
    ~RAIIHandleA() { DeleteAObject(Handle); }
}
...
```

On first glance, the RAII/Exceptions version seems longer, until you realize that the cleanup code needs to be written only once (and there are ways to simplify that).  But the second version of DoSomeThings is much clearer and maintainable.

DO NOT try and use exceptions in C++ without the RAII idiom, as you will leak resources and memory.  All your cleanup needs to be done in destructors of stack-allocated objects.

I realize there are other ways to do the error code handling, but they all end up looking somewhat the same.  If you drop the gotos, you end up repeating clean up code.

One point for error codes, is that they make it obvious where things can fail, and how they can fail.  In the above code, you write it with the assumption that things are not going to fail (but if they do, you'll be protected by the RAII wrappers).  But you end up paying less heed to where things can go wrong.

Comment: You can also combine RAII and regular error codes. A return statement is somewhat equivalent to a throw, in the regard that both will call the dtors of the stack objects that are in scope. So no goto's are needed.

Comment: Good point.  In my head error codes are always for C, so my brain didn't make the leap.

Answer (score 10):

Exception handling is useful because it makes it easy to separate the error handling code from the code written to handle the function of the program. This makes reading and writing the code easier.

Answer (score 8):

- return an error code when an error condition is *expected* in some cases
- throw an exception when an error condition is *not* expected in any cases

in the former case the caller of the function must check the error code for the expected failure; in the latter case the exception can be handled by any caller up the stack (or the default handler) as is appropriate

Answer (score 8):

Aside from the other things that were mentioned, you can't return an error code from a constructor. Destructors either, but you should avoid throwing an exception from a destructor too.

Answer (score 5):

I wrote a blog entry about this ([Exceptions make for Elegant Code](http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/design/exceptions-make-for-elegant-code.html)), which was subsequently published in [Overload](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/1505). I actually wrote this in response to something Joel said on the StackOverflow podcast!

Anyway, I strongly believe that exceptions are preferable to error codes in most circumstances. I find it really painful to use functions that return error codes: you have to check the error code after each call, which can disrupt the flow of the calling code. It also means you can't use overloaded operators as there is no way to signal the error.

The pain of checking error codes means that people often neglect to do so, thus rendering them completely pointless: at least you have to explicitly ignore exceptions with a `catch` statement.

The use of destructors in C++ and disposers in .NET to ensure that resources are correctly freed in the presence of exceptions can also greatly simplify code. In order to get the same level of protection with error codes you either need lots of `if` statements, lots of duplicated cleanup code, or `goto` calls to a common block of cleanup at the end of a function. None of these options are pleasant.

Comment: RAII is an idiom compatible with error codes as well as exceptions. You can also benefit from destructors cleaning up in case of a return statement after an error. Also, IMHO overloaded operators should not throw if possible.

Answer (score 2):

[Here's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics#Exceptions) a good explanation of EAFP ("Easier to Ask for Forgiveness than Permission."), which I think applies here even if it's a Python page in Wikipedia. Using exceptions leads to a more natural style of coding, IMO -- and in the opinion of many others, too.

Answer (score 2):

When I used to teach C++, our standard explanation was that they allowed you to avoid tangling sunny-day and rainy-day scenarios. In other words, you could write a function as if everything would work ok, and catch the exception in the end.

Without exceptions, you would have to get a return value from each call and ensure that it is still legitimate.

A related benefit, of course, is that you don't "waste" your return value on exceptions (and thus allow methods that should be void to be void), and can also return errors from constructors and destructors.

Comment: Throwing exceptions from destructors is widely considered to be a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

[Google's C++ Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml#Exceptions) has a great, thorough analysis of the pros and cons of exception use in C++ code. It also indicates some of the larger questions you should be asking; i.e. do I intend to distribute my code to others (who may have difficulty integrating with an exception-enabled code base)?

Comment: That is a great link. Interesting to note that Google does not use exceptions (because of existing code), but that "Things would probably be different if we had to do it all over again from scratch".

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you really have to use an exception in order to flag an exceptional case.  For example, if something goes wrong in a constructor and you find it makes sense to notify the caller about this then you have no choice but to throw an exception.

Another example:  Sometimes there is no value your function can return to denote an error;  any value the function may return denotes success.

```
int divide(int a, int b)
{
    if( b == 0 )
        // then what?  no integer can be used for an error flag!
    else
        return a / b;
}
```

Comment: Good example. Other one is callback functions that you pass to thirdy-party libs over which you have no control. Exception handling might then also be the only way to get an error out.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you have to acknowledge exceptions is correct but this can also be implemented using error structs. 
You could create a base error class that checks in its dtor whether a certain method ( e.g. IsOk ) has been called. If not, you could log something and then exit, or throw an exception, or raise an assert, etc...

Just calling the IsOk on the error object without reacting to it, would then be the equivalent of writing catch( ... ) {}
Both statement would display the same lack of programmer good will.

The transport of the error code up to the correct level is a greater concern. You would basically have to make almost all methods return an error code for the sole reason of propagation. 
But then again, a function or method should always be annotated with the exceptions it can generate. So basically you have to same problem, without an interface to support it.

Answer (score 0):

As @Martin pointed out throwing exceptions forces the programmer to handle the error. For example, not checking return codes is one of the biggest sources of security holes in C programs. Exceptions make sure that you handle the error (hopefully) and provide some kind of recover path for your program. And if you choose to ignore an exception rather than introduce a security hole your program crashes.